# Why was my answer, on a migrated question, deleted by community?

Tags: support, deleted-answers, community-user

[My answer (10k+ on SO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15301083/335858) has been migrated along with the question from The "Programmers" site, and subsequently the question was closed as "not a real question".

Could moderators please let me know:

- **Why the question has been closed?**  - it is a rather real question, complete with a piece of code that has been added to the question on "Programmers" after I posted the first edit of my answer.
- **Why has my answer been deleted by community?** - to me this looks like an error in the Community heuristic, but I may be wrong.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The answer was deleted because the **migration got rejected** by the question being closed, so your answer was [transferred back to Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/189788/convert-letters-to-numbers), where the question has been reopened.

Everything eventually gets deleted so you don't get reputation for the post in two places. The question is left there as a stub to get to the other question. There's no reason to keep the answers around at that point, so they are immediately deleted. The question gets automatically deleted itself after 30 days.

Comment: +1 for an actual explanation of the process.

Comment: Ah, I should have checked "Programmers" first, thanks for the explanation!

Answer (score 4):

The migration was rejected because the question was found to be on topic for Programmers (and subsequently reopened there). For the technical nitty gritty behind rejected migrations leading to deletions and locks see [animuson's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170974/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-community/170976#170976).

Comment: Hmmm but that deletes the answers but keeps the question? That is an odd bug?

Comment: How on earth is that on topic for Programmers?

Comment: @six: See the comment that [Thomas Owens posted](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/189788/convert-letters-to-numbers?noredirect=1#comment366457_189788).

Comment: @RobertHarvey: how counterintuitive, but I have no skin in the P.SE game nor this question so it's not a problem :)

Comment: @six: Programmers needs a flowchart, so that people can figure out what's on-topic there.

Comment: @Robert: I've just found it best to avoid that side of the Internets; I don't get it and probably never will.

Answer (score 3):

The question was originally posted on Programmers. 5 community members voted to close as off-topic, but the question is actually on-topic for Programmers. Although it contains code, the question is asking about an algorithm and is not about implementation in any particular language. Per the Programmers FAQ, algorithm and data structures questions are on-topic. Questions that are on-topic shouldn't be migrated (even if they are on-topic on multiple sites) unless the original asker wishes it to be migrated (in order to get better answers).

I asked SO to reject the improperly-conducted migration and reopened the question on Programmers.

Comment: *"Any help is appreciate it, I will write it later in c#"*, seems like a particular language to me.

Comment: @sixlettervariables If you read the question of the text, he's not asking about a problem in C#. He's more interested in the algorithm, and not problems writing or debugging C# code. If someone wants to use C# as the language to discuss the algorithm, that's perfectly OK on Programmers as well.

Comment: @sixlettervariables Really? Because to me it seemed like they only cared about the algorithm and said they could handle the implementation themselves...

Comment: @Thomas: fair enough. I'd argue they've picked the wrong venue to solve a specific problem like that, but if P.SE allows it then I have no objections.

Comment: @sixlettervariables: I actually picked NARQ over off-topic because I couldn't decipher *that one sentence*.

Comment: @ThomasOwens: [So what now](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300139/what-is-the-c-sharp-code-to-convert-an-excel-column-letter-into-its-number-with)? If this were left migrated on SO we would only have 1 (poor) question.