# What does "Deleted by Community" mean?

Tags: discussion, deleted-questions

[This question](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/coding-marathons-without-office-chair-or-other-office-seating-device/) on The Workplace was recently deleted.

Interestingly, it shows as

> deleted by Community♦ 15 mins ago

In searching Meta.Stackoverflow, I have been unable to determine what this actually represents.

I suspect it is related to the question having been

> migrated from programmers.stackexchange.com Feb 16 at 10:22

The reason I ask is I had what I thought was a good answer there and found it was deleted after tracking down some missing reputation.

---

The following was the sequence:

1. Question successfully migrated (over a month ago)
2. Question closed (a few days later, shows who closed it)
3. Question deleted today (well over 1 month after migration/closure, by "community")

Comment: I think this might be a duplicate: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170974/why-was-my-answer-deleted-by-community though I can't see the actual question you've linked to.

Comment: @Bart I believe it is a related issue, however that is talking about answers which are posted prior to migration and not the question itself being deleted

Comment: Yes, but I think the scenario is similar. A rejected migration causes the Community user to take the responsibility for the deletion of all affected posts. I'm 99% certain that's what happened here. Maybe there is a nicer dupe...let's have a look.

Comment: @Bart Well, it was a successful migration, so that doesn't seem to apply.

Comment: The migration message will appear upon migration, afaik. It then still can be rejected and be sent back to the site it came from.

Comment: @enderland It's not counted as a successful migration if the answer was closed when brought to the migrated site: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138460/168352

Comment: [text cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:IqAw4cZZBrcJ:workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/9721/coding-marathons-without-office-chair-or-other-office-seating-device&hl=en&strip=1) - it got closed on Workplace => failed migration.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When a migrated question gets closed on the target site it means the migration failed, as explained [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/170976/140505).

This means that the community user will end up deleting it, as fully explained by Shog9 [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/138460/140505).

As animuson commented, if the question was migrated for *duplicate* or *off-topic belongs on*, they are exempt from this process.

As Sathya commented, migration stubs like this are deleted after 30 days.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how the question is closed (which shows users who voted to close) and then deleted (which does not show users who voted to delete)

Comment: @enderland - Automated process. I don't know how often the job runs, but that's what it is.

Comment: "automated process" meaning closed migrated questions are automatically deleted? Or what?

Comment: @enderland - Yes. Exactly that. A question gets migrated - the target community closes it, meaning it shouldn't have been migrated (failed migration). An automated process then deletes it, as it shouldn't have been migrated in the first place.

Comment: @Oded In this case, would you happen to know if the question is returned to its source site? Or is it simply gone altogether?

Comment: @Bart - This particular question was deleted by a Mod on the source site. I suspect that if it were not, it would have been restored.

Comment: Ah, okay. Thanks for the info.

Comment: @Oded what about duplicates?

Comment: @enderland: A migration rejection only occurs for questions which get closed for any reason other than *duplicate* or *off-topic belongs on*, so closing as a duplicate would not reject the migration and thus not cause an automated deletion on the target site (it would be automatically deleted on the original site instead).

Comment: Migration stubs are deleted after 30 days..

Comment: "This particular question was deleted by a Mod on the source site" - I applaud your use of capitalization, not all mods are Mods ;)

Comment: @Yannis - I was wondering if anyone would notice. A Mod did ;)